# Django - Why PATCH returns in response correct data which I would like to save but it doesn't save this data in database?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

Any ideas why PATCH returns in response correct data which I would like to save but it doesn't save this data in database?

```
from .serializers import ObjectSerializer

@permission_classes([UserPermission])
class ObjectDetail(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer

    def patch(self, request, object_id):

        try:
            object = Object.objects.get(id=object_id)
        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = ObjectSerializer(object, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=Object

        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py:

```
class Object(models.Model):

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    field3 = models.FloatField()
    field4 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.field4 = self.field3
            super(Object, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**UPDATE**

I found the reason why my PATCH method doesn't work. The problem is with `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` function in model. When I comment it everything works fine. Any ideas how can I solve it?

Comment: I've never used the built in Django `serializer`s before, but if I understand correctly, you need to de-serialized to save it to the backend. Snippet from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/):

 "Calling DeserializedObject.save() saves the object to the database."

Comment: @DragonBobZ Can you show me how it should be done in this example?

Comment: I didn't want to give an example because I don't have a way to verify that it works and I've never used it myself. I guess the first thing I would try based on what you've shared would be to replace `serializer.save()` with `updated_obj = serializers.deserialize("json", data)` and `updated_obj.save()`. Now that I'm looking more closely, I'm not even sure that you've actually serialized the data at all. You never do a `serialize` call like in this snippet: `data = serializers.serialize('xml', Restaurant.objects.all())`. Can you show me where the ObjectSerializer class is imported from?

Comment: @DragonBobZ So you don't use PATCH method in you projects?

Comment: @DragonBobZ I updated source code in question.

Comment: I use PATCH, but I use the serializers from Django Rest Framework. Hold on, I did not see DRF there before.

Comment: This conversation is getting too long. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162377/discussion-between-dragonbobz-and-john-smith).

Comment: @DragonBobZ My serializer looks as shown above. Maybe there is easier and more optimal way to solve this?

Comment: I'm confident this code should work as it is pasted. If it doesn't, either you striped the part containing your issue, either we'll need the full Object model definition and what / how you are querying the API to help.

Comment: @Linovia I can't also understand why it's not working. I updated question with `Object` model. What do you need more?

Comment: @Linovia Maybe problem is associated with `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`?

Comment: @Linovia Yes it is. I commented this function then made migrations and everything works fine. Any ideas how can I solve it with this function?

Comment: Sure. You're not calling the super's save when pk exists - ie when you're updating the instance.

Comment: @Linovia How can I change it?

Comment: unindent the call to super.

Comment: @Linovia seems to be working properly. Can I ask you one more question associated with PATCH?